# How to create a new Time instance for today and only hour and minute are specified

Tags: ruby

I'm using following way to create a Time instance that have specified `hour` and `minute` and rest are today.

```
Time.new(Date.today.year, Date.today.month, Date.today.day, hour, minute)
```

or

```
d = Date.today
Time.new(d.year, d.month, d.day, hour, minute)
```

So I have to write three times similar expression `Date#year`, `Date#month` and `Date#day`. Is there more succinct way to write this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `Time.parse`:

```
require 'time'
Time.parse("16:30")
#=> 2015-02-23 16:30:00 -0500
```

Note from the [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/time/rdoc/Time.html#method-c-parse):

> You must require 'time' to use this method.

Comment: Perhaps make more general by writing `hour = 15; minute = 3; Time.parse("%d:%02d" % [hour, minute]) #=> 2015-02-22 15:03:00 -0800 `.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [spickermans answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28667061/676874) you could extend Time to get an easier function:

```
require 'time'
class Time
  def self.today(hour=0,minute=0)
    d = Date.today
    self.new(d.year, d.month, d.day, hour, minute)
  end
end

p Time.today            #-> 2015-02-23 00:00:00 +0100
p Time.today(12)        #-> 2015-02-23 12:00:00 +0100
p Time.today(12,30)     #-> 2015-02-23 12:30:00 +0100
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also write it like so:

```
hour = 15
minute = 21

require 'date'
Date.today.to_time + 60*(60 * hour + minute)
  #=> 2015-02-22 15:21:00 -0800
```